# C# - What is the most efficient way to build a string based on a set of boolean values

Tags: c#

I have 7 boolean values. Based on their values, I need to build a string. What is the most efficient way to do this?

For the sake of example, my boolean values are:

```
bool green = false;
bool red = true;
bool purple = true;
bool orange = false;
bool black = true;
bool blue = true;
bool brown = false;
```

Each boolean variable (theoretically) has a string associated to it. The final string I want to generate is dependent on the 'true' values.

Here, the string I want to generate is `"redskins - ravens - raiders - texans"`.

The strings associated to the 'false' variables would not be included in the final string.

The actual problem I am working on is larger in scale, with around 50 boolean values and my requirements have 50 string associated to them.

Is there anything more efficient than a large `if-else` method using `StringBuilder`?

My variable names do not represent the strings I need to output.

Comment: How did you "associated" a string to it?

Comment: since you need to check for each boolean variable simple if (colour) {} check for all boolean varible will do the best checking

Comment: Honestly, the best way to do this is use a Dictionary data structure, where the key is the string and value is the bool. This way you can just iterate over the keys. and add it to the string in a loop.

Comment: @Guilherme i have requirements that say, for example, if 'green' is true then add 'Packers' to the output string.

Comment: I think you should - like @MattWilkinson said - organize that in some collection structure. I also recommend a dictionary, but only if your strings did not repeat (distinct values).

Comment: The most common method is to use an integer with each bit being a color and true = 1 and false = 0;  So Green is bit 0, red is bit 1, purple is bit 2.  You can easily define using an  enum  Colors : long { GREEN = 0, RED, PURPLE, ORANGE, BLACK, BLUE, BROWN}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
bool green = false;
bool red = true;
bool purple = true;
bool orange = false;
bool black = true;
bool blue = true;
bool brown = false;

var bools = new Dictionary<string, bool>
{
     { $"{nameof(green)}", green}
    ,{ $"{nameof(red)}", red}
    ,{ $"{nameof(purple)}", purple}
    ,{ $"{nameof(orange)}", orange}
    ,{ $"{nameof(black)}", black}
    ,{ $"{nameof(blue)}", blue}
    ,{ $"{nameof(brown)}", brown}
};

Console.Write(string.Join("-", bools.Where(b => b.Value).Select(b => b.Key)));
```

Comment: That is a very clever, very concise solution. Really like it.

Comment: I like this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of using a dictionary for pairing.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> pair = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        pair.Add("green", "green");
        pair.Add("red", "redskiins");
        pair.Add("purple", "ravens");
        pair.Add("orange", "orange");
        pair.Add("black", "raiders");
        pair.Add("blue", "texans");
        pair.Add("brown", "brown");

        List<string> display = new List<string>();

        bool green = false;
        bool red = true;
        bool purple = true;
        bool orange = false;
        bool black = true;
        bool blue = true;
        bool brown = false;

        if (green)
            display.Add(pair["green"]);
        if (red)
            display.Add(pair["red"]);
        if (purple)
            display.Add(pair["purple"]);
        if (orange)
            display.Add(pair["orange"]);
        if (black)
            display.Add(pair["black"]);
        if (blue)
            display.Add(pair["blue"]);
        if (brown)
            display.Add(pair["brown"]);

        string finalStr = string.Join(" - ", display);
        Console.WriteLine(finalStr);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var boolArray = GetLotsOfBools();
var strArray = GetLotsOfStrings();

return string.Join(" - ",
   boolArray
   .Select((@bool, x) => new {
      Bool = @bool,
      Str = strArray[x]
   }).Where(pair => pair.Bool)
   .Select(pair => pair.Str)
   .ToArray()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, using a dictionary indexed to the input string (the color), and a tuple as a value:

```
        // Create your dictionary, indexed with the color, with a tuple as a value to describe
        // boolean state and matching string fragment
        var dictTeams = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<bool, string>>()
        {
            { "green", new Tuple<bool, string>(false, "packers") },
            { "red", new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "redskins") },
            { "purple", new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "ravens") },
            { "orange", new Tuple<bool, string>(false, "bears") },
            { "black", new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "raiders") },
            { "blue", new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "texans") },
            { "brown", new Tuple<bool, string>(false, "browns") }
        };

        // You can either initialize your dictionary all at once or fill it in later on.
        dictTeams.Add("white", new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "patriots"));

        // Select the keys of the entries marked true and aggregate them into a string.
        // Here you could also add a filter for only colors selected in another list by adding
        // a constraint in the Where clause using the key in addition to the boolean value.
        var outString = dictTeams.Where(c => c.Value.Item1)
                                 .Select(c => c.Value.Item2)
                                 .Aggregate((a, b) => a + " - " + b);
```

Note that Tuples are immutable, so if the boolean state needs to change at runtime, create a two fields class for your dictionary value instead, so you can then do something like:

```
dictTeams["green"].BoolState = false;
```

and

```
var outString = dictTeams.Where(c => c.Value.BoolState && lstUserColors.Contains(c.Key))
                         .Select(c => c.Value.StringFragment)
                         .Aggregate((a, b) => a + " - " + b);
```